# getServingUrl() Method using Google Cloud Storage value

Tags: java, google-app-engine

how would you create a basic URL for an image using getServingUrl() without using Blobs? All the examples I've seen so far involved blobs, but I need to use Google Cloud Storage value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is a new overload for `getServingUrl()` with a `ServingUrlOptions` method argument. And its builder has a `withGoogleStorageFileName()` method that you can use to create a URL based on the Cloud Storage filename.

```
GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename("bucketName", "objectName");
ImagesService is = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService(); 
String filename = String.format("/gs/%s/%s", gcsFilename.getBucketName(), gcsFilename.getObjectName());
String servingUrl = is.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename));
```

Javadocs:

1. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService.html#getServingUrl(com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions)
2. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ServingUrlOptions.Builder.html

Comment: The /gs/ in the url causes a none url, removing it causes exception 'Google storage filenames must be prefixed with /gs/', what should I do?

Comment: Should be the same if you do: 
ImagesService is = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService(); 
String filename = String.format("/gs/%s/%s", "bucketName", "objectName");
String servingUrl = is.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename));

I mean you don't need to use 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
   <version>0.7</version>
  </dependency>

  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but this is how you serve images from Cloud Storage:

```
String key = "/gs/<bucket-name>/<path>"; // Such as /gs/example-bucket/categories/animals.png"
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder
                .withGoogleStorageFileName(key)
                .imageSize(900) // Optional.
                .crop(true); // Optional.
String servingUrl = imagesService.getServingUrl(options);
```

Then you do whatever you want with the URL. For instance, you redirect request there.

That URL may have more options than `imageSize` and `crop` but Java API provided does not seem to support it. You could, however, append additional options to the URL string but this is not a matter of GCS but rather Images API.

Comment: I tried the above lines of code and I'm getting the following exceptions - 
Exception in thread "main" com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'blobstore' or call 'CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKey()' was not found.
You have any idea?

Comment: @das It seems like an incompatible or missing runtime dependency. `mvn dependency:tree` is your friend :D

You should look into the full stack-trace and determine which artifact it comes from. Also, try googling for this function (in most cases `<function name> github` query works like a charm). Figuring out in which artifact it is supposed to be will help you determine whether it's actually missing or just just wrong version.

Comment: @das I'm having the exact same issue. Did you manage to fix it somehow?