# How can I upload to BlobStore from a url in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

How can I upload a file programmatically from a url to BlobStore?

For instance, when using Facebook login, my app gets the url of the profile picture, and would like to fetch it and upload it to BlobStore. The examples in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob does not help, as my app knows the url, but I don't want to involve the user in the uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Google Cloud Storage for storing such files.

See Appengine examples at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

Comment: I would like to use the getServingUrl() of BlobStore, but based on what you are saying, that is not an option?

Comment: You can serve them directly from Cloud Storage, as well as upload directly to the Bucket. I believe Blobstorage was just a wrapper around Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thank you, I found this, so probably I can achieve the same thing with Cloud Storage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904891/getservingurl-method-using-google-cloud-storage-value