# Google storage filenames must be prefixed with /gs/

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use the code from this question [getServingUrl() Method using Google Cloud Storage value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904891/getservingurl-method-using-google-cloud-storage-value)

```
GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename("bucketName", "objectName");
ImagesService is = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService(); 
String filename = String.format("/gs/%s/%s", gcsFilename.getBucketName(), gcsFilename.getObjectName());
String servingUrl = is.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename));
```

I don't understand why there is /gs/ in the beginning of the path - it causes the code to produce a url that doesn't exist. but when I remove it I get 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Google storage filenames must be prefixed with /gs/'

So back to the original question - how to get a serving url from a GCS file?

I can do

```
"http://storage.googleapis.com/"+ filename.getBucketName()+"/"+  filename.getObjectName()
```

but it breaks on local server, thus I assume is not the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to access the file. If you access the file directly from the client (browser), then you can use a public URL:

```
"http://storage.googleapis.com/"+ filename.getBucketName()+"/"+  filename.getObjectName()
```

If you access this file internally - in your code, or call `getServingUrl()`, you use "/gs/" prefix. For example:

```
Image picture = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromFilename("/gs/" + filename.getBucketName() + "/" + filename.getObjectName());

GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename(filename.getBucketName(), filename.getObjectName());
```

I think there is just a problem with the file name in your example.

Comment: What do you mean problem with the file name? my question is - given a filename, how do I create a serving url that is valid, please give a full code example

Comment: Your code is correct, and it works for me. Make sure that you pass the correct file name - and it should work.

Comment: the filename is correct since this works -"http://storage.googleapis.com/"+ filename.getBucketName()+"/"+  filename.getObjectName()

Comment: locally = Local development server

Comment: When you say "does not work", you have to be more specific. What error message do you see?