# using getServingUrl() Method with Google Cloud Storage throws an error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm storing objects in the Google Cloud Storage in the following format

```
bucketname/UUID/object
```

I have a java method that returns a download link in the following format, to view the file

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/uuid/object?GoogleAccessId
```

Now, What I'm trying to do is to write a java method that would resize the object, in case of images.

EDIT : This is the class that connects to GCS.

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Base64;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Notification;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ServingUrlOptions;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminSettings;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient;
import com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminSettings;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BucketInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.HttpMethod;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.BlobListOption;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage.SignUrlOption;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageClass;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectSubscriptionName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.ProjectTopicName;
import com.google.pubsub.v1.PushConfig;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


/**
 * This class connects to the Google cloud storage and handles bucket/object related operations.
 *
 * @author Roshan
 */
public class GoogleCloudStorage {

  private ServiceAccountCredentials creds;
  private String saEmail;
  private Storage storage;
  private ClassLoader classloader;
  private TopicAdminSettings topicAdminSettings;
  private SubscriptionAdminSettings subscriptionAdminSettings;
  private String projectId;
  private Logger log;

  public GoogleCloudStorage() throws IOException {
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    /* Initialize credentials, service account email and other required stuffs. */
    this.classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("Key.json");
    if (is != null) {
      this.creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(is);
    } else {
      log.error("Inputstream from credentials file cannot be null.");
    }
    this.storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
        .setCredentials(creds)
        .build()
        .getService();
    this.saEmail = creds.getClientEmail();
    this.projectId = creds.getProjectId();
    this.topicAdminSettings = TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(creds)).build();
    this.subscriptionAdminSettings = SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(creds)).build();
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   *
   * This method creates a bucket, named as the given argument.
   */
  public void createBucket(String bucketName) {
    String topicId = "give topic id here";
    if (checkIfBucketExists(bucketName)) {
      log.info("Bucket already exists!");
    }
    storage.create(
        BucketInfo.newBuilder(bucketName)
            // See here for possible values: http://g.co/cloud/storage/docs/storage-classes
            .setStorageClass(StorageClass.COLDLINE)
            // Possible values: http://g.co/cloud/storage/docs/bucket-locations#location-mr
            .setLocation("europe-north1")
            .build());
    setBucketNotification(bucketName, topicId);
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   * @param uuid String
   * @param objectName String
   * @param mimeType String
   * @return String
   * @throws IOException This method sends POST request to the signed URL using custom headers and
   * an empty body, which returns the actual upload location in the response header.
   */
  public String getUploadLink(String bucketName, String uuid, String objectName, String mimeType)
      throws IOException {
    if (!checkIfBucketExists(bucketName)) {
      createBucket(bucketName);
    }
    URL myURL = new URL(getSignedUrlToPost(bucketName, uuid, objectName, mimeType));
    HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", mimeType);
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("x-goog-resumable", "start");
    // Send post request
    myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(myURLConnection.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    int responseCode = myURLConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode != 201) {
      log.error("Request Failed");
    }
    return myURLConnection.getHeaderField("Location");
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   * @param blobName String
   * @return String
   *
   * This method returns a downloadlink, valid for 10 minutes, based on the given bucket and object
   * name.
   */
  public String getDownloadLink(String bucketName, String blobName) {
    return storage.signUrl(
        BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName, blobName).build(),
        10,
        TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
    ).toString();
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   * @param uuid String
   * @return String
   *
   * This method returns an object name, based on the given bucketname and uuid.
   */
  public String getFileName(String bucketName, String uuid) {
    final String[] fileName = {null};
    Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName, BlobListOption.prefix(uuid));
    blobs.iterateAll().forEach(
        blob -> fileName[0] = blob.getName()//.substring(blob.getName().lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    );
    return fileName[0];
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   * @param uuid String
   * @param objectName String
   * @param mimeType String
   * @return String
   *
   * This method signs and return the URL to POST, using credentials from above. An uploadlink is
   * generated after a POST request is sent to the URL returned by this method, as used by
   * 'getDownloadLink()' above.
   */
  private String getSignedUrlToPost(String bucketName, String uuid, String objectName,
      String mimeType) {
    String signedUrl = null;
    try {
      String verb = "POST";
      long expiration = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + 60;
      String canonicalizedExtensionHeaders = "x-goog-resumable:start";

      byte[] sr = creds.sign(
          (verb + "\n\n" + mimeType + "\n" + expiration + "\n" + canonicalizedExtensionHeaders
              +
              "\n" + "/" + bucketName + "/" + uuid + "/" + objectName).getBytes());
      String urlSignature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(sr));
      signedUrl = "https://storage.googleapis.com/" + bucketName + "/" + uuid + "/" + objectName +
          "?GoogleAccessId=" + saEmail +
          "&Expires=" + expiration +
          "&Signature=" + URLEncoder.encode(urlSignature, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("Caught an Exception {}", ex);
    }
    return signedUrl;
  }

  /**
   * @param topicName String
   * @throws IOException This method creates a topic, based on the given topic name, needed to
   * publish/subscribe messages.
   */
  public void createTopic(String topicName) throws IOException {
    try (TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create(topicAdminSettings)) {
      ProjectTopicName projectTopicName = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicName);
      topicAdminClient.createTopic(projectTopicName);
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param topicId String
   * @param subscriptionName String
   * @throws IOException This method creates a subscription, that handles pull message delivery.
   */
  public void createSubscription(String topicId, String subscriptionName)
      throws IOException {
    try (SubscriptionAdminClient subscriptionAdminClient = SubscriptionAdminClient
        .create(subscriptionAdminSettings)) {
      ProjectTopicName topic = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
      ProjectSubscriptionName subscription = ProjectSubscriptionName
          .of(projectId, subscriptionName);
      subscriptionAdminClient
          .createSubscription(subscription, topic, PushConfig.getDefaultInstance(), 10);
    }
  }

  public String getResizedImage(String bucketName, String uuid) {
    GcsFilename gcsFilename = new GcsFilename(bucketName, getFileName(bucketName, uuid));
    ImagesService is = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
    String filename = String.format("/gs/%s/%s", gcsFilename.getBucketName(), gcsFilename.getObjectName());
    return is.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename));
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   * @param topicId String
   *
   * This method sets bucket notification that publish messages on the event of an upload.
   */
  private void setBucketNotification(String bucketName, String topicId) {
    List<String> eventType = new ArrayList<>();
    eventType.add("OBJECT_FINALIZE");
    try {
      Notification notification = new Notification();
      notification.setTopic(topicId);
      notification.setEventTypes(eventType);
      notification.setPayloadFormat("JSON_API_V1");

      final GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
          .fromStream(Objects.requireNonNull(classloader.getResourceAsStream("Key.json")))
          .createScoped(Collections.singletonList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL));

      final com.google.api.services.storage.Storage myStorage = new com.google.api.services.storage.Storage.Builder(
          new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), googleCredential).build();

      Notification v = myStorage.notifications().insert(bucketName, notification).execute();
      log.info("{}", v);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error("Caught an IOException {}", e);
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param bucketName String
   * @return boolean
   *
   * This method checks whether a bucket with given bucket name exists or not and returns a boolean
   * value of either true or false.
   */
  public boolean checkIfBucketExists(String bucketName) {
    return storage.get(bucketName, Storage.BucketGetOption.fields()) != null;
  }
}
```

This is Junit Test class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import service.GoogleCloudStorage;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class GoogleCloudOperationsTest {

  private GoogleCloudStorage service;
  private Logger log;      

  @Before
  public void setup() throws IOException {
    service = new GoogleCloudStorage();
    log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());        
  }

  @Test
  public void testIfBucketExist() {
    assertTrue(service.checkIfBucketExists("bucketName"));
  }   


  @Test
  public void testDownloadLinkGeneration() {
    String uuid = "uuid";
    String objectName = service.getFileName("bucket", uuid);
    String downloadLink = service.getDownloadLink("uuid", objectName);
    assertNotNull(downloadLink);
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(downloadLink)) {
      log.info(downloadLink);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testDownloadLinkGenerationAfterResize() {
    String uuid = "uuid";
    String objectName = service.getFileName("bucket", uuid);
    String downloadLink = service.getResizedImage("bucket", objectName);
    assertNotNull(downloadLink);
    log.info(downloadLink);
  }    
}
```

This is `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>google-cloud-operations</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-operations</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>1.72.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <version>1.72.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The credentials file `Key.json` resides inside the `resources` directory.
But, when I test `getResizedImage(String bucketName, String uuid, Integer size)`, it throws the following error.

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: Can't make API call blobstore.CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKey in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager

at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException.foreignThread(ApiProxy.java:800)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:112)
at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:65)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.createGsBlobKey(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:312)
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:266)
at service.GoogleCloudStorage.getResizedImage(GoogleCloudStorage.java:240)
at operationstest.GoogleCloudOperationsTest.testDownloadLinkGenerationAfterResize(GoogleCloudOperationsTest.java:64)
```

The error is occuring at

```
return is.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename).imageSize(size).crop(true));
```

I have no idea what's causing this. Could really use some help.

Edit : My solution attempt is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24149461/4131849).

Comment: I did not manage to reproduce the issue given the code you provided. I'd require the entire project's code to be able to fully dive into this. In the meantime, as an alternative, I recommend you to have a look at the official [documentation][1] on downloading/uploading GCS objects using various programming languages.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-java

Comment: @Maxim Thank you very much for your response. I can provide you with the entire project's code where I have already implemented the uploading and downloading part. There's no issue there. The only part I'm stuck is with the one mentioned in the post. Should I push it to git and send you the link, or e-mail?

Comment: Hello, after giving it a second thought, I believe it would rather be too complicated to work with the full code. Instead, are you able to provide the minimal code needed to reproduce the issue? If so, please do so and make sure you remove all personally sensitive information beforehand.

Comment: @Maxim The whole project contains just one Class file and a test file. I can remove my credentials json file from the project and send it to you. Would you prefer to have it e-mailed to you? If so, I'm gonna need an e-mail address to share that.

Comment: If so, then please just edit the original post, adding the necessary code to be able to run the file, without having to edit it any further by anyone attempting to run it.

Comment: @Maxim sure thing! I'll have the post edited.

Comment: @Maxim I've edited the post. You should be able to run it with your own credentials file in json, placed inside resources directory.

Comment: @Maxim any news on the matter?